# Pandas and joining uneven shaped Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm really new to Pandas and need some help.

I have two dictionaries that I get from a mysql database and I create two dataframe using the from_dict() function.

```
import pandas as pd

x = [{'username': '123456789123456789', 'COUNT': 2}, {'username': '446525523352255253', 'COUNT': 2}, {'username': '71714562323332787', 'COUNT': 2}]

y = [{'asked_by': '145256321122455563', 'COUNT': 1}, {'asked_by': '123456789123456789', 'COUNT': 1}]

r1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x)
r1.columns = ["Username", "Unanswered_Questions"]

r2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(y)
r2.columns = ["Username", "Answered_Questions"]
```

The thing is x will not always be greater than y nor y greater than x. It changes depending on what's in the DB.

I'm trying to join the two dataframes and fill 0 if there's missing values.

```
Username             Unanswered_Questions    Answered_Questions
446525523352255253         2                          0
717145222323332787         2                          0
123456789123456789         2                          1
145256321122455563         0                          1
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try outer merge:

via [`merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) method and [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method:

```
out=r1.merge(r2,on='Username',how='outer').fillna(0)
```

If needed use [`astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) method:

```
out[['Unanswered_Questions','Answered_Questions']]=out[['Unanswered_Questions','Answered_Questions']].astype(int)
```

Output of `out`:

```
    Username            Unanswered_Questions    Answered_Questions
0   123456789123456789          2                       1
1   446525523352255253          2                       0
2   71714562323332787           2                       0
3   145256321122455563          0                       1
```